# Clean it up, and [diy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) has many, many questions, that could be closed. This tag is also EXTREMELY meta. I propose we get rid of it, quickly... And with a [can-do](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/can-do) attitude

Comment: A few are about building computer-related equipment.  Not sure [computer-building] would apply to peripherals, accessories, and components, or at what point that crosses the line to off-topic.  DIY repairs covers half the questions here, like [hardware] and [software], and we don't have a [take-it-to-the-shop] tag.  "Who does it" is basically an off-topic tag, irrelevant to the site.

Answer (score 6):

Done. All remaining [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) questions are closed; the others have been edited to remove that tag and fix other minor issues. (I also did my best to remove the hardware recommendation aspect when it appeared.) I certainly agree that [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) provided no categorization value - it was used on all sorts of things, from hardware improvisation to hardware replacement to novel software setups.

Comment: Ben, thanks.  But just FYI, while I doubt anybody would complain on this one, there's a protocol for bulk changes.  Generally, you should wait for a moderator to tag it [status-planned], or at least give it a reasonable period for community comment.  People do sometimes move ahead with cleanup if, after a week or so, there's extensive upvotes and no issues raised.  No matter how obvious the cleanup may appear, there's always a chance that somebody will identify a legitimate twist or exceptions that other people didn't catch.

Answer (score 2):

So… I started my own cleanup on [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy)—including *removing* the tag from some posts—and then decided, maybe there is a valid reason [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) needs to exist? It seems nebulous and many of the posts fall into categories of tutorials or even hardware recommendations that are off topic.

Knowing that, should the posts be flagged to be “closed” if they are off topic and the [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) stays? Or should things be flagged to be “closed” if off topic and the [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) should slowly disappear as well.

Comment: I suggest removing them completely. Almost all the troubleshooting an average user would do is do it yourself

Comment: Plus, there is no expert on "diy" specifically